# Kivy - Addressing An Ellipse Widget Created In KV Language Using Python

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I'd like to control a simple Ellipse widget created in Kivy using KV Language. I have been working on this for days having read and worked through the exercises in the book Kivy: Interactive Applications in Python by Roberto Ulloa and Ben Rousch's online workshop at https://bradfortner.wordpress.com/2017/07/19/good-kivy-tutorial/.

While the examples provided in those tutorials seem to work fine on pre-defined Kivy widgets (ie. Buttons and Labels) I'm having trouble controlling Widgets that I define such as a circular ellipse as shown in the code below.

In the code (below) I create the circular ellipse class Widget (named Ball) on lines 10 and 45. I place the Ball Widget on my layout (line 29) and then id the Widget as my_circle (line 30). Finally I provide the code to link the widget to Python (line 26) so Python code can control the Widget.

However when I press the "Shrink Circle" button and the shrink_circle() function is called there is no effect on the widget. Any idea where the code goes wrong? I'd love to know because it's become quite the mystery to me and I cant find anything simple that explains what I need to do to correct this.

Full code below.

Appreciated in advance.

....brad....

```
# Modified from https://github.com/brousch/pyohio-kivy-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial/step11_tts/saythis.kv

import kivy
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
kivy.require("1.9.1")

Builder.load_string('''
<Ball>:
    size: 1, 1
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Ellipse:
            pos: 350,290
            size: 70,70
<ShrinkThis>:
    button_font_size: '30sp'
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:        
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    my_circle: my_circle
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Ball:
            id: my_circle
        Button:
            text: 'Shrink Circle'
            font_size: root.button_font_size
            size_hint: 1, None
            on_press: root.shrink_circle()            
''')

class ShrinkThis(BoxLayout):

    my_circle = ObjectProperty(None)

    def shrink_circle(self):
        self.my_circle.size = (10,10)

class Ball(Widget):
    pass

class ShrinkThisApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ShrinkThis()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ShrinkThisApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that kivy `canvas` is not a widget and it isn't the space in which you paint, it is just a **set of instructions** to draw. `Ball` should be a widget.

On the other hand, the `size` property **is ignored** if `size_hint` property is not disabled.

**Simplified example:**

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.9.1")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


Builder.load_string('''
<Ball@Widget>
    size: 70, 70
    pos: 350,290
    size_hint: None, None

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<ShrinkThis>:
    button_font_size: '30sp'
    my_circle: my_circle

    Ball:
        id: my_circle
    Button:
        text: 'Shrink Circle'
        font_size: root.button_font_size
        size_hint: 1, None
        on_press: root.shrink_circle()            
''')
```

**Output:**

[image: enter code here]

Answer (score 0):

Now that the mystery is solved and for completion of this question I've posted the full working code below. I also added position change to this updated code so those who see this in the future will know how to code for position change as well.

Also to be fair to Roberto Ulloa who wrote Kivy: Interactive Applications in Python to Ben Rousch's online workshop;

- Ulloa's book did address the widget addressing as corrected by FJSevella in the above code. While his book is good Ulloa may have put too much in a single chapter using multiple .kv files that confused me. I thought that addressing () was being used to reference the different .kv files.
- Rousch's online workshop did not address Kivy's canvas which is something else I'm trying to wrap my brain around even though I've read 10 things you should know about the Kivy canvas several times. (http://robertour.com/2013/07/19/10-things-you-should-know-about-the-kivy-canvas/).

Below is the complete working code;

```
# Modified from https://github.com/brousch/pyohio-kivy-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial/step11_tts/saythis.kv
# And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45217816/kivy-addressing-an-ellipse-widget-created-in-kv-language-using-python

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
kivy.require("1.9.1")

Builder.load_string('''
<Ball@Widget>
    size: 70, 70
    pos: 350,290
    size_hint: None, None
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
<ShrinkThis>:
    button_font_size: '30sp'
    my_circle: my_circle
    Ball:
        id: my_circle
    Button:
        text: 'Shrink & Reposition Circle'
        font_size: root.button_font_size
        size_hint: 1, None
        on_press: root.shrink_reposition_circle()            
''')

class ShrinkThis(FloatLayout):

    my_circle = ObjectProperty(None)

    def shrink_reposition_circle(self):
        self.my_circle.size = (10,10)
        self.my_circle.pos = (300, 500)

class Ball(Widget):
    pass

class ShrinkThisApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ShrinkThis()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ShrinkThisApp().run()
```